# implementing an interface which is a subset of parent

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have interfaces as follows:

```
interface TableColumn {
  column: string;
  returnType: any;

  // some other fields, not relevant ...
  constraints?: Constraints[];
}

interface Status extends TableColumn {
  column: 'status';
  returnType: string;
}

interface Title extends TableColumn {
  column: 'title';
  returnType: string;
}

interface PostProperties {
  status: Status;
  title: Title;
  // and other properties...
}
```

I'd like to use the above to generate, in effect the following interface:

```
interface PostDbResponse {
  status: string;
  title: string;
}
```

I've tried using mapped types and `keyof` to achieve this but have not been able to sucessfully. Is it even possible to do this?

The actual goal is to use the schema data to generate a return type from query methods. However, I'd also like to be able to define various return types based off of what fields we're selecting to begin with.

I can make all fields in the returned response optional, but that is not ideal. I'm open to other implementation ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
type PostDbResponse = {
    [K in keyof PostProperties]: PostProperties[K]["returnType"]
};
```

For each key `K` of `PostProperties` (for example, `status`), we take the type of the property `K` of `PostProperties` (for example, `Status`) and then the type of the `returnType` property of that type.

Comment: yes, brilliant. Thank you. I can use Pick<PostProperties, 'aProperty', 'anotherProperty'> to get a subset. Next I need to figure out a generic way to build that DbResponse type so it doesn't have to be "table" specific

Comment: Is it possile to do this but for interfaces?